# Reference Requiest: Representation Theory of Diffeomorphism Groups

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, topological-groups, diffeomorphism

[This wonderful and insightful Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_diffeomorphism_groups) page contains a lot of interesting facts about representations of diffeomorphism groups.  However, there are no references.

In general, I'm curious if $Diff_k^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ denotes the orientation-preserving $C^k$-diffeomorphism group of $\mathbb{R}^d$ which stabilizes $0$.  They claim that $Diff^{\infty}_x(\mathbb{R}^d)/Diff^{1}_x(\mathbb{R}^d)$ can be identified with $GL(\mathbb{R}^d)$.  Where can I find this fact?  More interestingly, what can we say about
$$
Diff^{\infty}_x(\mathbb{R}^d)/Diff^{k}_x(\mathbb{R}^d),
$$
for $k\geq 2$ (besides it being finite-dimensional) and *where can I find a nice book about these wonderful things?*

Comment: Your notation is not consistent with the link you provided.  There all the diffeomorphisms are in $C^\infty$ and $Diff_x^k$ denotes those diffeomorphisms that fix $x$ and agree with the identity map at $x$ to $k$th order. I'm not sure about a reference though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the title of your question is slightly misleading, what you are looking at is jet groups rather than diffeomorphism groups. So these are finite dimensional Lie groups rather than the infinite dimensional diffeomorphism groups and they are independent of the manifold one considers. Of course, they do give rise to representations of the groups of diffeomorphisms fixing a point, but again these do not see the manifold.

In my opinion, the defintion that is chosen in the Wikipedia page you link is not the most transparent one. There is a general notion of $k$-jets of smooth maps between manifolds. In particular, for each $k$ and fixed $n$, you can consider $k$-jets at $0$ of smooth maps $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ which map $0$ to $0$. In there the jets of diffeomorphisms form an open subset and a group $G^k_n$ under compositions. For $k=1$, a 1-jet of such a smooth map is a linear map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ (representing the derivative of the map at $0$) and this is the 1-jet of a diffeomorphism if and only if it is a linear isomorphism. Hence $G^1_n\cong GL(n,\mathbb R)$ and mapping a $k$-jet to the underlying 1-jet defines a surjective homomorphism $G^k_n\to G^1_n$, so each jet group is an extension of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$. To get to your language, you can send a diffeomorphisms of $\mathbb R^n$ that fixes $0$ to its $k$-jet, thus defining a surjective homomorphism $Diff_0(\mathbb R^n)\to G^k_n$ for each $k$. The kernel of this homomorphism is what you denote by $Diff^k_0(\mathbb R^n)$, since as mentioned in the comment by @Nate, these are diffeomorphisms that equal the identity to $k$th order.

Representations of the jet groups are closely related to natural vector bundles and thus to geometric objects on smooth manifolds. This is discussed in the book "Natural Operations in Differential Geometry" by Kolar, Michor and Slovak, that is availble online via Peter Michor's homepage [here](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/listpubl.html#books) . But there is not as much explicit representation theory in that book.

Comment: Can we construct a particular type of Jet bundle such that $G^{k}_{n} \rightarrow Diff_0$  as $k \rightarrow \infty$?   i.e. such that our Jet groups are better and better approximation of the stabilizer of diffeomorphisms at the identity as we move to higher order?  Under what conditions can we create such an object? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450033/nth-order-approximation-of-point-stabilizing-diffeomorphisms-by-nth-order-jet-gr

Comment: I think it requires that $Diff^{k}_{0} \rightarrow Identity$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. It is clear that in the smooth setting (both for functions and for diffeomorphisms) there is a significant difference between germs (i.e. locally defined objects) and infinite jets (which correspond to infinite order Taylor polynomials). So you always loose a significant amount of information by passing to an infinite jet.